# How to enable voice in Microsoft webchat Bot

Tags: node.js, azure, chatbot

I successfully develop a webchat bot on Microsoft Azure using **Node JS** as back end.
everything is working fine, Now I want to integrate voice in bot, like we have in google assistant or Alexa.

Problem is there is no clear documentation from Microsoft to implement this with Nodejs
if anybody done this before kindly help.
thanks

Comment: You could refer to [Interactive Voice Response Bot](https://gallery.azure.ai/Solution/Interactive-Voice-Response-Bot).

Comment: I built the bot using this tutorial:please tell me how can i integrate voice in it
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/intelligence-LUIS

Comment: This solution is under maintenance and will not be available until further notice.